# Magento 2 - How to set format datetime for all system

Tags: magento2, date, format

How to set format datetime for all system ?

Such as: date attributes of entity(product, customer etc), import, export etc

Anyone know, please show me step by step.

Comment: I don't fully understand what is mean "format datetime for all system"? Datetime is formatted based on locale

Comment: @Kandy we are facing same issue need date time format dd/mm/yyyy but its showing mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 1):

You need override `date.js` file from:

> vendor/magento/Magento_Ui/web/js/form/element/date.js

To your `vendor/Theme`, ex.:

> /app/design/frontend/Your_Vendor_Name\Your_Theme_Name/Magento_Ui/web/js/form/element/date.js

Choose your features and date format options and deploy new static files:

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/*
```

And run Magento2 CLI command:

```
php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
```

If Magento Cache in use/enable, need clean , run command:

```
php -f bin/magento cache:clean
```